# Use handlebars template helpers in hapijs

Tags: javascript, requirejs, handlebars.js, hapi.js

I'm using jquery's typeahead in hapijs using a handlebar view. It works with static source data. I want to use data from a postgresql-database but I don't know how to include the pg-bluebird npm module.

I've done a similar jquery typeahead in meteorjs where I get the source from a mongodb collection using the template name and then call a template event from javascript like:

html:

```
<template name="participantItem">
    ... html form input etc. ...
</template>
```

javascript:

```
Template.participantItem.events({
    'click .edit': function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#club").autocomplete({
           /* query remote source */
        });
    }
});
```

When I try to add `<template name="foo">` to my html file in hapijs it loads the content but the page is not rendered except for the header and footer.

I like the way meteorjs is using helper templates and events and would like to do it the same way in hapijs.

I ended up including javascript to test typeahead with static data in the html file but it does not appear to be very elegant.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
       ... content using some json data ...
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#states').autocomplete({
            delay: 500,
            minLength: 2,
            source: states
        });
    }
</script>
```

I call the view like this from index.js:

```
var Pgb = require('pg-bluebird');
var pg = new Pgb();
var db = "postgresq://claus@localhost/karusellrenn";
    exports.register = function (plugin, options, next) {
        plugin.route([
            {
                method: 'GET',
                path: '/participants',
                handler: function (request, reply) {
                    .then(function (result) {
                        cnn.done();
                        reply.view('participants', { p: result.rows});
                    .catch(function (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                });
            }
        }
    ]);
    next();
};
```

Can I use handlebars in hapijs the same way I use handlebars in meteorjs like `<template name="foo"></template>` and then make use of a javascript helper like `Template.foo.events({});`?

And if not, can I use pg-bluebird included in index.js in my handlebars view inside  in the handlebars view?

Comment: I'm not sure what your real question is. Can you use handlerbars in hapijs - yes. Can you make use of a database module in your views - well not directly but you can do in your route handlers. Maybe you can focus your question more and tell us exactly what's not working.

Comment: Pardon, I've updated the question. Hopefully it helps clarify my question.

Comment: I would suggest a thorough reading of this: http://hapijs.com/tutorials/views It explains how hapi renders views/helpers/layouts etc with handlebars as the example

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I made a basic page with some data from a postgresql query reading the tutorial. I'll see if registering a handlebars helper using [handlebarsjs.com/block_helpers](http://handlebarsjs.com/block_helpers.html) as a starting point is a viable solution. Defining the html input text field and the associated jquery plugin and requirejs code.